# json_contains issue with the query, like

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json

I try to find a food with some categories stored in the categories column as json.

My query : `select * from`foods`where json_contains(categories, '["Aliments"]')`

this should return at list one element who have in categories column is content :

```
[
    "Aliments et boissons à base de végétaux",
    "Aliments d'origine végétale",
    "Matières grasses",
    "Matières grasses végétales",
    "Huiles"
]
```

what i'm doing wrong with the query ?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Just because you use json format doesn't mean that you are not storing multiple values in a column. Which almost always indicates a poor database design.

Comment: version MYSQL 8

Comment: it's better if i use pivot table ? food_category to store? @HoneyboyWilson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON_CONTAINS` does not work as `LIKE`, it just looks for exact values. You should first extract the field and then run a `LIKE` query against. Since you are searching in root (according the data you gave) you need something like;

```
select * 
from foods 
where json_extract(categories,'$') LIKE '%Aliments%'
```

Answer (score 2):

`JSON_CONTAINS()` searches for exact match, and does not implement pattern matching.

Since you are using MySQL 8.0, you could use `json_table()` to unnest the array and then do pattern matching on each element:

```
select f.*
from foods f
where exists (
    select 1 
    from json_table(f.categories, "$[*]" columns(cat varchar(255) path "$")) c
    where c.cat like '%Aliments%'
)
```